# Mvn command error

Tags: java, git, maven

When I executed  this command:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=trident.Myclass
```

I got this:

```
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] Compilation failure

error: error reading /home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/13.0/guava-
13.0.jar; 
error   in opening zip file

error: error reading /home/user/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-   

core/2.0.0/jackson-core-2.0.0.jar; error in opening zip file error: error reading 

/home/user/.m2/repository/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-core/3.0.3/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar; 

error in opening zip file
```

What to do? (I can't post pom file, because I need at least 10 reputation.)

Comment: Have you added M2_HOME and its path in system environment variable?

Comment: i'm new in maven. how can I check it ?

Comment: Open a command prompt and type mvn -version and press enter

Comment: are you vote me down ?! yes i'm weak in java . what's a problem of copy-paste error message !??? how can you know the problem i face to solve it ?

Comment: @user3928141 I fixed the terrible writing quality of your question, answered the best as I could, changed my downvote to up, and removed my angry comments. This is what you won't got from anybody here, you will be only voted out, thus please repair your writing quality very, very fast in your next posts.

Comment: After mvn - version i got Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8) Java version: 1.6.0_38 Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_38/jre Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux" version: "3.5.0-23-generic" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: What on the spot visible is: you didn't copied the whole error message, which can be a cause of the actual downvotes you got.

Second: your maven looks for his repository in `/home/.m2/repository`. It is nearly surely not the place of your maven repo. It need to be probably in `/home/<yourusername>/.m2/repository`. There is some problem in your system: as @SasikumarMurugesan commented out, you had probably to set up an `M2_HOME` environment variable with the correct place to that.

Third: what maven wants, is a file named `guava-13.0.jar`, which must be practically a normal zip file (only with the `.jar` extension). Probably this file is missing on your system, or it is damaged. With a command `unzip -t /path/to/your.jar` you can test if a jar file is valid and undamaged. It lists its contents, and if it is undamaged, you don't get any error message.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to get my attention next times in shaa allah . i edited the post with the whole errors i got i hope i can find solution.

Comment: how can i post pom file as i tried to post it and i got this "it looks like your post is mostly code please add some more details"

Comment: @user3928141 Don't post the whole pom.xml, only its relevant parts + give clear text also with that. But this current question is already closed, so the best what you can do, to re-accept my answer, and make a new question. I will poll for that. Good luck!

Comment: @dimo414 I think you are right - no prob.